# How to get image ID based on get_theme_mod image URL?

Tags: images

I'm trying to use `wp_get_attachment_image` function to insert image. For that I need use *image ID*. So now I need to know how to get this ID by image URL taken from `get_theme_mod` from WP Customization API.

So:

```
$image_src = get_theme_mod('header_logo', '');
$image_id = HOW TO GET ID FROM $image_src ??
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'logo' );
```

I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671108/get-attachment-id-by-file-path-in-wordpress/31743463 so I was trying:

```
// retrieves the attachment ID from the file URL
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
        return $attachment[0]; 
}

// set the image url
$image_url = get_theme_mod('header_logo', '');

// store the image ID in a var
$image_id = pippin_get_image_id($image_url);

// print the id
echo $image_id;

// final image
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'logo' );
```

but still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a built-in function for this: [`attachment_url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/).

More info from a Stack Overflow question: [Get Attachment ID by File Path in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671108/get-attachment-id-by-file-path-in-wordpress).

Comment: 'attachment_url_to_postid' is what I'm looking for, thanks!